# Eclipse marketplace and install new software option missing in my eclispe

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarlint, marketplace

I want to install sonarlint plugin.But in my eclipse neither marketplace nor install new software option available. I know generally these options are available under Help.[image: here is my Help options pic]

my eclipse version is Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)
Build id: 20221201-1913

could someone help to resolve this issue

Comment: Are you running Eclipse using Java 17 or newer? How was it installed?

Comment: The menu items might depend on the chosen perspective. The _About Eclipse IDE_ item is missing too. Consider to do a fresh installation of the current version (2023-09).

Comment: @howlger The location of the *About Eclipse IDE* action is OS-dependent. On macOS, the standard for About dialog actions and Quit are that they're on a menubar menu for the application as a whole.

Comment: @nitind I see. Thanks for correcting me.